# How to configure CloudFront using CloudFormation to set the 'Headers' property in 'ForwardedValues' to 'all'?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudfront

I am setting up CloudFront using CloudFormation, but I need to configure the [`Headers`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-cloudfront-distribution-forwardedvalues.html#cfn-cloudfront-distribution-forwardedvalues-headers) property of the [`ForwardedValues`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-cloudfront-distribution-cachebehavior.html#cfn-cloudfront-distribution-cachebehavior-forwardedvalues) property. It should be setup in such a way that ***all*** headers are forwarded.

I can't find how to do so on neither the [`ForwardedValues` documentation page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-cloudfront-distribution-forwardedvalues.html#cfn-cloudfront-distribution-forwardedvalues-headers) nor [the page that is linked regarding Caching Content Based on Request Headers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/header-caching.html).

This is the CloudFormation 'path' to the `Header` property:

```
someCloudFrontDistributionName:
    Type: AWS::CloudFront::Distribution
    Properties:
        CacheBehaviors:
            ForwaredValues:
                Headers:
                - # What to put here that will allow all Headers to be forwarded?
```

Comment: this is I see in getdistrinbution config: "ForwardedValues": {
                        "Headers": {
                            "Items": [
                                "*"
                            ], you can try it

Comment: This is indeed what I tried for now, but I still haven't had the time to validate. Would you mind putting your comment as an answer? If it is correct I will accept it as the correct answer for this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is I see in getdistrinbution config:

```
"ForwardedValues": { "Headers": { "Items": [ "*" ]
```

You can try it to see if this works.

Comment: When I tried this technique it did not work. Here's some details about what happened when I tried : https://gist.github.com/gene1wood/c0249066d2562e410ddecd8a6fee8306

Answer (score 5):

Using Yaml:

```
    Headers: ["*"]
```

An example inside the "ForwardedValues" element for some context:

```
    ForwardedValues:
        Cookies:
          Forward: all
        Headers: ["*"]
        QueryString: true
```

Please note that this might lead to poor performance (allegedly) due to the caching of "Date" headers as documented [[here]](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/RequestAndResponseBehaviorCustomOrigin.html#request-custom-headers-behavior)

Comment: Shouldn't it be - "*" for YAML?