# Set Cloudfront "Cache Based on Selected Request Headers" to All in Cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudfront

In Cloudformation, How can you set "Cache Based on Selected Request Headers" to All for Cloudfront?

From what I understand, this is equal to not caching at all. However, in the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-cloudfront-distribution-defaultcachebehavior.html) `Forwarded Values` is a required field. It is also mentioned in the docs that `You must create exactly one default cache behavior`

[image]

Comment: see if this is helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57291562/how-to-configure-cloudfront-using-cloudformation-to-set-the-headers-property-i/57328128#57328128

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for. My question was a duplicate

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate of [How to configure CloudFront using CloudFormation to set the 'Headers' property in 'ForwardedValues' to 'all'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57291562/how-to-configure-cloudfront-using-cloudformation-to-set-the-headers-property-i/57328128#57328128)

As answered by @James Dean

```
"ForwardedValues": { "Headers": { "Items": [ "*" ] } }
```